# SQL Sever 2008 R2 - Lock table during clear and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

We have a need to (once per month) clear out the contents of a table with 50,000 records, and repopulate, using a Stored Procedure.  The SP has a User Defined Table Type parameter which contains all of the new records to be inserted.

The current thought is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [ProcName]
  @TableParm UserTableType READONLY
AS

[Set lock on table?]

BEGIN TRAN
  DELETE FROM [table]

  INSERT INTO [table](column, column, column)
  SELECT (a.column, a.column, a.column) FROM @TableParm a
COMMIT TRAN

[Remove lock from table?]
```

I've read some solutions which suggest to set READ COMMITED or READ UNCOMMITED... but figured I'd turn to the pro's to steer me in the right direction, based on the situation.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a serializable transaction

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
```

Both the `READ...` type levels would allow data of some form to be read from the table, which is probably not what you want.

You may also be able to use `TRUNCATE TABLE` rather than `DELETE`, depending on your data structure.

If reducing the unavailability of this table is an issue, you may be able to reduce it by creating a new table, populating it, then renaming the old and new tables.

Comment: thank you. we arent too concerned about availability, it should take less than a second to run.  I will try the Serializable command and if it works mark this answer.